# php if and or syntax

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm struggling to make this statement work

```
if(((!isset($_COOKIE['email']) && !$_SESSION['remember_me']) || $_SESSION['id']) {
 //do something
} else {
 //do something
}
```

I want it to return true if both of the first two statements are met, or if the third statement is met?

Comment: Logically, this works fine, but you need to either tell us what values your variables need to be holding to make the `if()` true, or what's not working with your current code.

Comment: I removed the extra bracket, still doesn't work, already played around with it. There are other places on the page where the $_SESSION['id'] is called and they work fine, so it can't be because that isn't set, unless it's because they use isset, which I'm going to try now

Comment: Oh, I know, I've done it backwards! I should be looking to see if the session id is not set :D sorry guys and thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have one too many `(` at the start of the line. Other than that, there's no reason why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ((!isset($_COOKIE['email'] && !$_SESSION['remember_me'])) || $_SESSION['id'] )
```

That should work, if i correctly understand what you want